# How can I sequence within a group in mySQL (works in workBench not in NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have a query that will properly sequence in mySQL workBench, but not in NodeJS against the same DB.

Query:

```
 SELECT 
      users.userId,
      users.firstName,
      users.middleName,
      users.lastName,
      users.address,
      users.address2,
      users.city,
      users.stateProvince,
      users.postalCode,
      users.country,
      users.email,
      users.mobilePhone,
      users.altPhone,
      users.ataId,
      users.pitaId,
      users.nssaId,
      users.nscaId,
      users.active,
      @seq := IF(@saveUserId = user2, @seq + 1, 0) as seq,
      permissionsPlus.entityId,
      permissionsPlus.entityName,
      permissionsPlus.entityTypeId,
      permissionsPlus.entityTypeName,
      permissionsPlus.permissionSettings,
      permissionsPlus.roleId,
      permissionsPlus.roleName,
      permissionsPlus.userPermissionId,
      @saveUserId := permissionsPlus.user2 as user2
    FROM sosclays.users
    LEFT JOIN   
     (SELECT userPermissions.*, 
      entityTypes.name AS entityTypeName, 
      IFNULL(sanctioningBodies.name, IFNULL(associations.name, IFNULL(clubs.name, IFNULL(shoots.name, 'App')))) AS entityName, 
      roles.name AS roleName,
      @user2 := userId as user2
      FROM userPermissions 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sanctioningBodies ON(entityTypeId = 1 AND userPermissions.entityId = sanctioningBodies.sanctioningBodyId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN associations ON(entityTypeId = 2 AND userPermissions.entityId = associations.associationId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs ON(entityTypeId = 3 AND userPermissions.entityId = clubs.clubId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN shoots ON(entityTypeId = 4 AND userPermissions.entityId = shoots.shootId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN entityTypes ON(userPermissions.entityTypeId = entityTypes.entityTypeId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN roles ON(userPermissions.roleId = roles.roleId)
      ORDER BY userPermissions.userId ASC) permissionsPlus on(users.userId = permissionsPlus.userId)
      ORDER BY users.userId ASC, seq ASC
```

Can you think of reasons why it works in WorkBench but not in NodeJS?   How might I best resolve this or use an alternative approach?

Essentially, I'm looking for a sequence number starting at 0 for each of many permissions pulled from the permissionsPlus part of the query.

In mySQL workbench I see the following correct sequence (third row, seq column)  for user E7skP0IncSW7wkBxnrYFx6udzGH2

[image]

In NodeJS, the seq column values are always 0.  Also - when using PHPMYAdmin, the seq column values are always 0.

Comment: Describe the exception. Provide context. Provide exception log.

Comment: Please build a dbfiddle for your code  , basically the @ variables have to be Declared

Comment: what does not working look like?  what *does* happen?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you're using 8.x, you should use the `RANK()` window function instead of user variables.

Comment: I'm using 8.x.   I'm not getting any errors in NodeJS, all sequences are set to 0.   (in WorkBench, the sequences are correct).   I'm not familiar with RANK

Comment: Since the queries are identical, is it possible that some sessions variables in workbench are different that NodeJS?

Comment: Correction:   Workbench version is 8.x, mySQL is 5.7.34

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SET @seq = 0;
 SET @saveUserId = '';
 SELECT 
      users.userId,
      @seq := IF(@saveUserId = users.userId, @seq + 1, 0) as seq,
      permissionsPlus.entityId,
      permissionsPlus.entityName,
      permissionsPlus.entityTypeId,
      permissionsPlus.entityTypeName,
      permissionsPlus.permissionSettings,
      permissionsPlus.roleId,
      permissionsPlus.roleName,
      permissionsPlus.userPermissionId,
      @saveUserId := users.userId as saveUser
    FROM sosclays.users
    LEFT JOIN   
     (SELECT userPermissions.*, 
      entityTypes.name AS entityTypeName, 
      IFNULL(sanctioningBodies.name, IFNULL(associations.name, IFNULL(clubs.name, IFNULL(shoots.name, 'App')))) AS entityName, 
      roles.name AS roleName
      FROM userPermissions 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sanctioningBodies ON(entityTypeId = 1 AND userPermissions.entityId = sanctioningBodies.sanctioningBodyId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN associations ON(entityTypeId = 2 AND userPermissions.entityId = associations.associationId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs ON(entityTypeId = 3 AND userPermissions.entityId = clubs.clubId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN shoots ON(entityTypeId = 4 AND userPermissions.entityId = shoots.shootId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN entityTypes ON(userPermissions.entityTypeId = entityTypes.entityTypeId) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN roles ON(userPermissions.roleId = roles.roleId)
      ORDER BY userPermissions.userId ASC) permissionsPlus on(users.userId = permissionsPlus.userId)
      ORDER BY users.userId ASC, seq ASC
```